# How to detect last element within a map iterator

Tags: c++, stl

I want to be able to detect the last iteration within my map iterator. How would I achieve this?

```cpp
class JSON {
public:
    static void stringify(map<string, string> data)
    {
        string base;

        base += "{ ";

        for (map<string, string>::iterator it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it)
        {
            cout << it->first.c_str() << " => " << it->second.c_str() << endl;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Note: `cout << it->first.c_str()` can be replaced with `cout << it->first`

Comment: I tried that and it threw this error: `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2679 binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type '_Ty1' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

Comment: What does your compiler say that `_Ty1` is equal to? Assuming you're using Visual Studio, this should be in the next line of output. Have you `#include`d `string` and `iostream`? Also, what version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I am including `<iostream>` however, I'm not including `<string>`. I'm running VS 2017 version 15.9.11

Comment: Well, you gotta `#include <string>` before you use `std::string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by creating an index, incrementing the index on every iteration of your map and then for each iteration comparing the size of your map to the index.

```cpp
class JSON {
public:
    static void stringify(map<string, string> data)
    {
        string base;
        int index = 0;

        base += "{ ";

        for (map<string, string>::iterator it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it)
        {
            if (data.size() - 1 == index)
            {
                // Do stuff here
            }

            cout << it->first.c_str() << " => " << it->second.c_str() << endl;
            index++;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use [std::prev](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) like this:

```
    for(auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it)
    {
        if(it == std::prev(data.end()))
        {
            // this is the last iteration
        }

        std::cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << '\n';
    }
```

[std::prev](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) returns the *previous* iterator from its parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Inside each loop iteration, you can check if the *next* iterator matches the map's `end()` iterator or not, eg:

```
static void stringify(map<string, string> data)
{
    string base;

    base += "{ ";

    auto it = data.begin();
    auto end = data.end();

    while (it != end)
    {
        auto next_it = std::next(it);

        if (next_it == end) {
            cout << "this is the last iteration!" << endl;
        }

        cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << endl;

        it = next_it;
    }
}
```

Or:

```
static void stringify(map<string, string> data)
{
    string base;

    base += "{ ";

    auto it = data.begin();
    auto end = data.end();

    if (it != end)
    {
        do
        {
            cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << endl;

            auto next_it = std::next(it);
            if (next_it == end) {
                cout << "that was the last iteration!" << endl;
                break;
            }

            it = next_it;
        }
        while (true);
    }
}
```

If your goal is just to avoid inserting a comma into your JSON output on the first or last iteration (depending on where in your code you want to do that insertion), you can do that like this:

```
static void stringify(map<string, string> data)
{
    string base = "{";

    auto it = data.begin();
    auto end = data.end();

    if (it != end)
    {
        cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << endl;

        base += (" \"" + it->first + "\": \"" + it->second + "\"");

        while (++it != end)
        {
            cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << endl;

            base += (", \"" + it->first + "\": \"" + it->second + "\"");
        }
    }

    base += " }";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply move the iterator bounds check into the body of the loop:

```
void stringify(map<string, string> data){
    string base;

    base += "{ ";

    for (map<string, string>::iterator it = data.begin();;){
        if (it == data.end()){
            cout << "Last iteration!";
            break;
        }
        cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << endl;
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Note that the code in the `if` statement will be called for an empty map.